# How to add doc ID to every element of querySnapshot from firestore query?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add the document `ID` from each doc in the query snapshot to the corresponding element in the array I am pushing then committing to state.

I need the document `ID` in my state so I can query specific docs by there id in order to update them.

I am currently looping through the snapshot with `forEach()` like the google docs suggest but I am trying to use `map()` to put each element in my let `cards =[]` array but also include the doc.id in the element somewhere.

```
     actions: {
      async nuxtServerInit(vuexContext, context) {
        let cards = []
        await db
          .collection('Assets')
          .get()
          .then(snapshot => {
          snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            cards.map(doc.data())
          })

          vuexContext.commit('setCards', cards)
        })
    },
```

Currently in my state I am still seeing

```
 loadedCards:Array[1]
0:Object
authors:"noFace1"
description:"hopefully this fucking works"
imageurl:Array[1]
slug:"the-big-test-bunny"
title:"The big test bunny"
type:"Video"
user:"VbomJvANYDNe3Bek0suySs1L8oy1"
```

I need to have another property of `id: xblkujoifduodsifl` (just example id) included in my state.

Answer (score 4):

change this line `cards.map(doc.data())` for this

```
cards.map(doc => {
  const id = doc.id
  const data = doc.data()
  return Object.assign({}, id, { ...data })
})
```

the id is not part of the doc unless you explicit copy it

Comment: I couldn't the code to work so I managed to fix it with let myData = doc.data()  myData.id = doc.id cards.push(myData)

Comment: cool, that works too, I just update the answer for others can benefit from it

Comment: This would work but is there really not a native way to do this with the firebase API?  This seems like such an intuitive thing to want.

Comment: what do u mean with "native" way? I'm using plain js for the answer

Comment: I expected the firebase JS api to support this natively, but I don't think it does.  If you are fortunate enough to be using `react-firebase-hooks`, you can pass in an `idField` option that will populate the data returned with the id field specified.

Comment: Great solution and it worked for me, but I think `return Object.assign({}, id, { ...data })` should be `return Object.assign({}, {id}, { ...data })` if you don't want each character in the id to get split up @andresmijares

Answer (score 1):

This is are more verbose solution from my code that worked:

```
.db
  .collection("organizations")
  .doc(activeOrganization)
  .collection("people")
  .get()
  .then((snapshot) => {
    if (!snapshot.empty) {
      let people = [];

      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        let dict = { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id};
        people.push(dict);
      });
      console.log(people);

    } else {
      reject("No document corresponding to the query!");
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => reject(err));
```